# Как использовать button с переменной?

Tags: winforms, c++

Я не хочу писать большого кода,кнопки уже созданы. Как заменить?

```
button4->Visible=false;
button5->Visible=false;
button6->Visible=false;
button7->Visible=false;
button8->Visible=false;
```

на

```
for (i = 4; i < 9; i++) {
    button i->Visible = false;
}
```

Помогите пожалуйста.
КНОПКИ СОЗДАНЫ В RUN-TIME

Comment: Возможно стоит их группировать в ComboBox и изменять его свойство отображения.

Comment: А что мешает при создании кнопок добавлять их в массив? А потом по массиву проходиться так как вы хотите.

Comment: Dex Ну так я не знаю как кнопки добавлять в массив при создании, подскажите.

Answer (score 3):

Что-то в последнее время подобные вопросы часто стали тут появляться.

Нет, в С++ так делать нельзя. Надо указатели на динамически созданные объекты (в данном случае - объекты кнопок) группировать в массивы или (намного лучше) в контейнеры, например, vector, и далее обращаться к ним через индекс.